# setspace complicates custom class: best workaround?

Tags: documentclass-writing, setspace

#### Background – class with 'transparent' key–value options

I have a custom class for thesis-like docs that allows setting fonts, styles, lengths, and rubber lengths with key–value options. It's a [work in progress](https://github.com/dmyersturnbull/desert-latex) (became a small kitchen sink), but it is pretty transparent to use, which was my main goal after struggling with various opaque behaviors in LaTeX packages:

```latex
\documentclass [
    font-size / main = 11.5pt , % any font size
    linespace / main = 1.25 , % any line spacing
    linespace / caption = 1.0 , % 
    glue / footer = 2ex plus 0.2ex minus 0.1ex ,
    glue-above / display = 2ex plus 2ex minus 1ex , % nice and stretchy
    glue-below / display = 2ex plus 2ex minus 1ex ,
    toc / depth = section ,
]{desert}
```

The values used are exactly what the user passes in.
Note that it's happy with any values (e.g. 10.775pt) for font size, leading, line spacing, and glue.

##### Setspace compatibility issues

[setspace](https://ctan.org/pkg/setspace) makes some choices that work nicely for most documents using article, report, and book, but can be glitchy. See the code here:
https://github.com/rf-latex/setspace/blob/main/setspace.sty

My intent is not to criticize the original authors -- I've happily used setspace for a decade, but it's started a sparring match with my fledgling class, and **setspace is a dependency of various packages.**

###### Setspace oddities

1. `displayskip` (`nodisplayskip` too) zeroes out the stretch and shrink components of `abovedisplayskip`, `belodisplayskip`, `abovedisplayshortskip`, and `belowdisplayshortskip`.
   (It does the same thing with `\baselineskip \baselinestretch\baselineskip`, but only for non-2e LaTeX; see [line 393](https://github.com/rf-latex/setspace/blob/02cf9e0c43a8caa30858f599c5ffb0c7565d4dd1/setspace.sty#L393).)
2. `singlespace`, `onehalfspace`, and `doublespace` environment, commands, and options examine the documentclass font option, looking for `10pt`, `11pt`, or `12pt`.

   - Spacing appears bigger in captions and footnotes (where the active font size is smaller than the documentclass one.)
   - It behaves quite differently for any font size other than 10, 11, or 12.
   - The leading produced seems unexpected. Double-spacing 'generally' means what you get by hitting return twice on a typewriter. So for 10pt font with 12pt leading, you get 12pt+12pt =24pt. Setspace adds an extra x-height instead of an extra line, for 12pt+10pt =22pt).
3. `\begin{spacing}{2.0}` produces different spacing than `\begin{doublespace}` because only the latter uses the leading + x-height definition. `\begin{onehalfspace}` has the same problem. As @Mico points out, the nullary switches (e.g. `\doublespacing`) work the same.
4. Vspace between adjacent spacing environments can be incorrect. (Best is probably `max{vspace-after-previous-paragraph, vspace-before-next-paragraph}`?)
5. It modifies footnotes by redefining `footins` and `mpfootins` to call `\def\baselinestretch {\setspace@singlespace}`.
6. It does something to `xfloat` on [line 425](https://github.com/rf-latex/setspace/blob/02cf9e0c43a8caa30858f599c5ffb0c7565d4dd1/setspace.sty#L425) that I don't understand.

##### Current workarounds ... & better ideas?

I null-out `\displayskip` and avoid using setspace's environments, commands, and options.
For footnotes, [footmisc](https://ctan.org/pkg/footmisc) seems to avoid setspace's changes. I'm ignoring #4 and assuming #6 isn't causing problems.

**Is there a better way to co-exist with setspace's functionality?**
The main goal for my class is transparency, and setspace has some pretty opaque behaviors. I'd rather not re-invent the wheel.

Comment: You don't mention the package's `\setstretch` macro, which more or less lets you achieve everything you say you want to achieve. E.g., `\setstretch{2}` is equivalent to "Double-spacing 'generally' means what you get by hitting return twice on a typewriter.", as you put it.

Comment: The best idea is to get rid of doublespacing once and for all. Ask your MP (or whatever they're called in your country) to propose a bill for making doublespacing illegal.

Comment: you could write your own setspace commands and then suppress the loading of setspace.sty.

Comment: @Mico True, I updated #3, which only hinted at that. While I can set spacing using that (or just `baselinestretch` etc.), setspace still adds lots of singlespacing hooks. Plus, the inconsistencies remain; if a user uses the widely used setspace macros and environments like `\doublespacing` anywhere, they get something that's different from what the key-value options they passed to the class, which is confusing. And it only happens if they're using 10, 11, or 12 pt -- even less transparent.

Comment: @Ulrike Fischer Hm. While not ideal, that may be a pragmatic choice (plus I really dislike packages that modify behavior just by being loaded). How could I suppress loading setspace.sty?

Comment: @egreg Certainly universities (update: and publishers!) should not require "double spacing" and "1.5 spacing" without specifying what they actually mean. In the US (where I am), this is really common problem. *(And yean, 'true' typewriter-style double-spacing is a bit excessive.)*

Comment: various package change something only by loading, e.g. hyperref and quite often that is wanted. How to prevent package loading is described in ltfilehook-doc.pdf, `texdoc ltfilehook-doc`.